# Adding Native Functionality BlackBerry10 in IBM MobileFirst 6.3

Tags: blackberry-10, ibm-mobilefirst

Based on this [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide/platforms/blackberry10/plugin.html).

I am adding native functionality on BlackBerry10 by doing this steps :

1. Creating the Native Class
2. Creating the Plugin's Javascript
3. Configure the plugin.xml :

This is the sample content of my config.xml on my Blackberry10 MFP project :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="Mordor" version="1.0.1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" rim:backButton="exit">
    <name>Mordor</name>
    <author email="application author's e-mail">application's author</author>
    <description>
       Mordor
    </description>
    <license href="http://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical">
    </license>
    <access subdomains="true" origin="file:///store/home" />
    <access subdomains="true" origin="file:///SDCard" />

    <!-- start_worklight_host_server do not change this line-->
  <access subdomains="true" origin="https://blablabla.com" />
  <!-- end_worklight_host_server do not change this line-->

    <access subdomains="true" origin="*" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <rim:splash src="splash-1024x600.png" />
    <rim:splash src="splash-600x1024.png" />
    <rim:splash src="splash-1280x768.png" />
    <rim:splash src="splash-768x1280.png" />
    <content src="webresources/skinLoader.html" />
    <rim:permissions>
        <rim:permit>read_device_identifying_information</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>read_geolocation</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>access_pimdomain_contacts</rim:permit>
    </rim:permissions>
 </widget>
```

This is the sample content of my config.xml on my Android MFP project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        id        = "Mordor"
        version   = "1.0.0.0">
    <name>Mordor</name>

    <description>
        Mordor
    </description>

    <author href="http://mycompany.com" email="application author's e-mail">
        application's author
    </author>

    <access origin="*"/>
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <!--
      <preference name="splashscreen" value="resourceName" />
      <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0xFFF" />
      <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
      <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />
      <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    -->
        <!-- This is required for native Android hooks -->
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="RootDetectionPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.Mordor.plugin.RootDetectionPlugin" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

For the android project, i just simply add this configuration below to my config.xml :

```
<feature name="RootDetectionPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.Mordor.plugin.RootDetectionPlugin" />
  </feature>
```

My question is : 
How to configure the config.xml for BlackBerry10 in the MobileFirst, so i can trigger the native function ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support for this, but the steps to accomplish the requirement should be similar to what is mentioned in the official Cordova guide with a few more steps: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide/platforms/blackberry10/plugin.html,
1. Similar to other plugins folder inside blackberry10/native/webresources/worklight/plugins/, you need to create folder for the plug-in (com.blackberry.test.hello).

2. create src/blackberry10 folder inside the plug-in and then create a folder for device and simulator in the src/blackberry10 folder, copy corresponding .so file into it
3. create a manifiest.json file inside src/blackberry10 which contains
   {"global": false, "namespace": "com.blackberry.test.hello", "dependencies": []}

   Make sure namespace should be same as feature name of plugin.xml.
4. Now create a "www" folder inside the plug-in, and store there the plug-in .js file.
5. Modify the .js file in the following way:

   - Add unique id (should be same as feature value of plugin.xml) 
     e.g. first line of js should be like:

   cordova.define("com.blackberry.test.hello.Hello", function(require, exports, module){
   ...
   ...
   content of your js});
6. in corodva_plugin.js inside blackberry10/native/webresources/worklight/, add entry for your customise plugin.

   e.g. 
    {

   ```
   "file": "plugins/com.blackberry.test.hello/www/Hello.js",

   "id": "com.blackberry.test.hello.Hello",

   "merge": [

       "Navigation"

   ]
   ```

   },

   Make sure the id in the .js and cordova_plugin.js is same as the feature value of plugin.xml. Also put merge/clobber, whatever is there in your plugin.xml.